# Azure ASP Web API error 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, azure, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api application that I have written and tested locally using VS2017 and IIS Express 10.  I am able to POST and GET when running locally using either HTTP or HTTPS.  When I publish to Azure I am getting method not allowed on both the post and get over HTTP.

How do I configure the Azure server to allow all the HTTP verbs?

How to configure HTTPS on Azure is another story...

Thanks :-)

Comment: Normally this should 'just work'. Add some logging (think about Application Insights) to see what's wrong. How are you calling the POST and GET method for testing purposes?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and the solution here worked.
Simply **change the http to https** in the POST call and test the result. For example in postman, only change the http to https.

[Azure App Service Error 405 - The request could not be completed. (Method Not Allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840070/azure-app-service-error-405-the-request-could-not-be-completed-method-not-al/47849073#47849073)

Comment: omg this saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are passing the **params** correctly. Wasted a lot of time figuring that out.

Comment: Agreed.. I kept getting a 405 response on a POST because my path was ".../_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=4.1-preview.1". When I removed "-preview.1," it started working: ".../_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=4.1." Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @TangereApps thanks, I had exactly the same problem. How did you figure out removing the "-preview.1" was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your web application uses a js library/framework (react / angular). Usually before the request, they send a preflight CORS request using the "Options" verb. I believe that it's the one that it's being blocked.

One easy way to solve this:

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

BaseApiController.cs:

```
 public class BaseApiController : ApiController
  {
    public HttpResponseMessage Options()
    {
      return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
  }
```

If it's a cross-domain problem, you can configure CORS directly through Azure portal:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
  var result = new ObjectResult("YOUR MESSAGE");
  result.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed;

  return result;
```

you need to add this => namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc