# Azure ReactJS with REST API deployment

Tags: rest, azure, unity-container

I am having a ReactJS app with REST API using Unity.AspNet.WebApi, which is working fine on local development environment. When I deploy it to Azure (using local git method) I am getting File Not found 404 error for my /api/ calls.

I tried the workaround (rewrite settings) given here https://medium.com/@skoob13/deploying-react-app-with-node-js-rest-api-on-azure-9b389251150a but that didn't solve the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using **ASP.Net Web API** (as you mentioned **Unity.AspNet.WebApi**), I think you should drop the following section (from the link you mentioned) from your configuration file, as the API calls shouldn't be directed to **Node.JS**:

```
<!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
<rule name="API Routes">
    <match url="^api\/.*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
</rule>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that global.asax was missing from the deployed folder, plus I had to enable CORS in Web.config as in this thread. 
[Azure ASP Web API error 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776644/azure-asp-web-api-error-405-method-not-allowed)